# Trouble in making Google Search Information program

Tags: google-search

I'm making a program that is google search result saver. **( related SEO.)**

> for example, if there is a word we are using seo keyword, we save this
>   keyword in our database.
>
> And then, In program (console program) we are sending google search
>   request. so that we can know our search result Ranking.

But Problem is **503 error** since July 11.
on the other hand, response from google is **503 Service unavailable**.

Maybe, I think my IP was blocked because there are many request in short time.

In this case, What can I do?

I've called google search call center, but I didn't get a solution.